# Adding strings in lists together

Tags: python, string, list

I want to transform the list `["A","B","A","A","B"]` to the list `["AB","BA","AA","AB"]`.

I have tried to define a new list in which the first element is deleted and then add the strings of the lists together. After which I plan to delete the last element of the new list to get the result.

```
lista = sequences
lista.pop(0)
print(lista)

for x in range(sequences):
    mc =sequences[x]+lista[x]
```

But all I get is

> TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Any help is welcome.

*Edit : Thank you guys, all your solutions worked perfectly :)*

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Best solution, using `zip` with a list comprehension, cleverest:

```
>>> l = ["A","B","A","A","B"]
>>> [x + y for x, y in zip(l, l[1:])]
['AB', 'BA', 'AA', 'AB']
>>>
```

Or use an `enumerate` with a list comprehension:

```
>>> l = ["A","B","A","A","B"]
>>> [v + l[i + 1] for i, v in enumerate(l[:-1])]
['AB', 'BA', 'AA', 'AB']
>>>
```

Answer (score 13):

Use `zip()`:

```
>>> lst = ["A","B","A","A","B"]
>>> [x + y for x, y in zip(lst, lst[1:])]
['AB', 'BA', 'AA', 'AB']
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map):

```
s = list(map(str.__add__, lst[:-1], lst[1:]))
```

A bit better to use [`operator.concat()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.concat) (thanks for advice, @MykolaZotko):

```
import operator

s = list(map(operator.concat, lst[:-1], lst[1:]))
```

---

**Upd.**

I've decided to do some tests on bigger data.

```
import operator

lst = [...] # list with 10000 random uppercase letters


def test1():
    return list(map(operator.concat, lst[:-1], lst[1:]))


def test2():
    return [x + y for x, y in zip(lst, lst[1:])]


def test3():
    return [v + lst[i + 1] for i, v in enumerate(lst[:-1])]


def test4():
    s = ''.join(lst)
    return [s[i:i + 2] for i in range(len(s) - 1)]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import timeit
    print(timeit.timeit("test1()", setup="from __main__ import test1, lst", number=10000))
    print(timeit.timeit("test2()", setup="from __main__ import test2, lst", number=10000))
    print(timeit.timeit("test3()", setup="from __main__ import test3, lst", number=10000))
    print(timeit.timeit("test4()", setup="from __main__ import test4, lst", number=10000))
```

**Results:**

1. Python 2:

   ```
   10.447159509
   11.529946446
   20.962497298000002
   20.515838672
   ```
2. Python 3:

   ```
   10.370675522
   11.429417197
   20.836504865999995
   20.422865353
   ```

On bigger data `map()` is a bit (~9%) faster, but there's no significant difference between `test1()` and `test2()`

Comment: You can use `operator.add` or `operator.concat` as well. Strange that `map` is faster. Normally `map` is slower than listcomp.

Comment: @MykolaZotko, it's not faster, few miliseconds slower, almost the same. I've done a mistake while copying data

Answer (score 4):

There are several issues in your original code:

```
sequences = ["A","B","A","A","B"]
lista = sequences
lista.pop(0)
print(lista)

for x in range(sequences):
    mc =sequences[x]+lista[x]
```

Firstly, the statement `lista = sequences` does not make a copy of sequences. Instead, `lista` and `sequences` become two different names for the same list. What you do using one name also happens to the other. `lista.pop(0)` is the same as `sequences.pop(0)`. If you want a copy, then import the `copy` library.

```
import copy

sequences = ["A","B","A","A","B"]
lista = copy.copy(sequences)
lista.pop(0)
print(lista)

for x in range(sequences):
    mc =sequences[x]+lista[x]
```

Secondly, your statement `range(sequences)` is incorrect. The `range()` function accepts integers as input, not lists. That's what gave you `TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`

```
# VALID
range(5)
range(3)
range(10)

# INVALID
range(["A","B","A"])
range(["eyes", "nose", "tail"])
```

`sequences` is a list. You want `range(len(sequences))` not`range(sequences)`

In the end, we can modify your original code to work:

```
import copy

sequences = ["A","B","A","A","B"]
lista = copy.copy(sequences)
lista.pop(0)
print(lista) # prints ["B","A","A","B"]

mc = list()
for x in range(len(lista)):
    mc.append(lista[x] + sequences[x + 1])
```