# Python String Editing

Tags: python, string

My Initial String consists of   ***`<span>` and some contents in between and a `</span></span`*** , I would like to remove that piece(*including span and contents inside it and /span*) from my string , what should I do ?

Part of String that need to be Removed : `"<span class="_5mfr"><span class="_6qdm" style='height: 16px; width: 16px; font-size: 16px; background-image: url("https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/images/emoji.php/v9/t81/1/16/")`+14 variable strings+`</span></span`

I would like to remove that whole piece mentioned above

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: The quick way would be `s = s.replace('<span>','').replace('</span>','')`.

Comment: @TimRoberts It Didn't Worked :(,it returned the same old string

Comment: @TimRoberts, no `>` in the `</span`

Comment: @PCM yeah by that most part of the ```span``` thing removed,but some part is till there like mentioned below

Answer (score 2):

```
import re

txt = 'Iam a good boy <span>some blahblahblah </span</span and my name is john'
print(re.sub(r'<span>.*</span</span ', '', txt))
```

Prints:

```
Iam a good boy and my name is john
```

**to the updated question**

```
import re

txt = """<span class="_5mfr"><span class="_6qdm" style='height: 16px; width: 16px; font-size: 16px; background-image: url("https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/images/emoji.php/v9/t81/1/16/")+14 variable strings+</span></span"""
print(re.sub(r'<span [^<>]*?</span>?</span', '', txt))
# prints: <span class="_5mfr">
```

Comment: Did this work with the string you updated in your question? I don't think the accepted answer solves for the current string.

Comment: Yeah,This Didn't Worked,I was using Except block with the program and I thought that problem had solved

Comment: Did you try this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/69218568/449378 ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `BeautifulSoup`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(string, 'html.parser')
for x in soup.findAll('span'):
    x.replace_with('')
print(soup.string)
```

Comment: It's not by me,Bro It's somebody Else

Comment: @SimpleGuy_ Ah! yeap! Hope it works for you!

Comment: Anyway,I've changed my question a little bit so that my aim is clear to everyone

Comment: @SimpleGuy_ Added working code, this is much more consistent

Comment: @SimpleGuy_ Great!

Comment: Bro,One more Doubt Please,is there any way by which I can combine the 2 consecutive items of a list into together.
Eg: The list contains even Number of Elements(All elements are Strings),I would like to concatenate 1st&2nd one as First String, 2nd&3rd string as Second string,etc. Like that...

Comment: @SimpleGuy_ I have an answer that does that :P [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56341236/adding-strings-in-lists-together/56341270#56341270), feel free to check it out

Comment: Bro I encountered a problem with my Original question (Main Question here),By trying your answer that whole string is converted to None

Comment: @SimpleGuy_ ???

Comment: When I tried out your solution,that whole string gets converted to None,I want to remove that part(Span and its containings),I want the remaining string

Answer (score 0):

You can replace everything found by the regex as shown below:

```
import re

regex = r"(<span.+?>)|(<\/span>)"

test_str = "<span class=\\\"_5mfr\\\"><span class=\\\"_6qdm\\\" style='height: 16px; width: 16px; font-size: 16px; background-image: url(\\\"static.xx.fbcdn.net/images/emoji.php/v9/t81/1/16/…\\\")'>© Dasamoolam Damu (Troll Malayalam)ഹൗ ക്രൂവൽ<span class=\\\"_5mfr\\\"><span class=\\\"_6qdm\\\" style='height: 16px; width: 16px; font-size: 16px; background-image: url(\\\"static.xx.fbcdn.net/images/emoji.php/v9/td7/1/16/…\\\")'></span></span></span></span>"

print(re.sub(regex, '', test_str))
```